# How to alias or rename the register in gas or avr-as?

Tags: assembly, avr, gnu-assembler

For example : I need to alias temp to r16 register.
In standart atmel`s compiler it can be done by .def directive:

`.def temp=r16`

But in avr-as(gas) it doesn`t work.

I  tried this :

```
    .set  temp, r16 
    #define temp r16  
    #define temp $r16
```

This methods don`t works with registers, only with constants.
I want to write like this:

```
    ldi temp,0xff
```

Please, help)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> #define temp r16
> ```

This is how I would have done it.

However, if you use C preprocessor instructions (such as `#define`, `#ifdef` etc.), you cannot directly pass the program to `as` but you have to invoke the preprocessor first.

If you are running `as` "indirectly" by calling `gcc`, you can use the file extension `.S` (upper-case "S") instead of `.s` (lower-case "s"). This tells `gcc` that the assembler file contains preprocessor instructions.

Alternatively you can use the `gcc` command line option `-x assembler-with-cpp`. This tells `gcc` that it should ignore the file name extension and treat the file like an `.S` file (even if the file name ends with `.c`).

Here the three options you have:

```
1) gcc -o myFile.o -c myFile.S

2) gcc -o myFile.o -x assembler-with-cpp -c myFile.s

3) cpp -o temporaryFile.s myFile.s
   as -o myFile.o temporaryFile.s
```

Comment: Thank you, I found  way 'gcc -E '

Answer (score 2):

One can use *constant* in register places.

```
$ cat t.s
.equiv temp, 16
    .text
    ldi r16, 0xCC
    ldi temp, 0xAA
    .end
$ avr-as t.s
$ avr-objdump -d a.out

a.out:     формат файла elf32-avr
Дизасемблювання розділу .text:
00000000 <.text>:
    0:  0c ec           ldi r16, 0xCC   ; 204
    2:  0a ea           ldi r16, 0xAA   ; 170
```

Indeed, I use preprocesor for redefining of register names to constants

```
#define r16 16 // and so on
```

So,  I can use arithmetical expressions in macro like

```
//----------------------------------    word add
.macro  add_w   dst:req, src:req
    add \dst, \src  $  adc \dst+1, \src+1
.endm
```